# php get times between tow times like 1:30:00AM

Tags: php, date

this code get count hours between tow times 
ineed out put like this

6:00:00AM
6:30:00AM
7:00:00AM
7:30:00AM
8:00:00AM
8:30:00AM
......
10:30:00PM

how i can do this

```
                                   $start = date_create('6:00:00AM');
                                    $end = date_create('11:00:00PM');
                                    $diff = date_diff($end, $start);
                                    print_r($diff->h);
```

Comment: What about 11pm to 8am? What about 8am to 8am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could use [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php) to build the list of dates on the desired specification, as opposed to iterating over comparisons of the date and adding the increment.

```
$start = date_create('6:00:00AM');
$end = date_create('11:00:00PM');
$interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minutes');
$periods = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($periods as $date) {
    echo $date->format('h:i:sA') . \PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result: https://3v4l.org/FnEae

```
06:00:00AM
06:30:00AM
07:00:00AM
07:30:00AM
08:00:00AM
08:30:00AM
//..
10:30:00PM
```

---

Since `\DateTime::diff()` won't always show the **total** hours between dates with different days, you can count the hours between the two dates by using `iterator_count` on the `DatePeriod` of the desired interval:

```
$start = date_create('6:00:00AM');
$end = date_create('11:00:00PM');
$interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 hour');
$periods = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
echo iterator_count($periods) . ' hours';
```

Result: https://3v4l.org/P75K7

```
17 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $start = date_create('6:00:00AM');
    $end = date_create('11:00:00PM');

    $halfHour = new DateInterval('PT1800S');
    while ($start < $end) {
      print ($start->format('h:i:sA').PHP_EOL);
      $start->add($halfHour);
   }                                 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Datetime objects and a date interval object and iterate while less than the end Datetime add the interval each time.

```
$start = date_create('6:00:00AM');
$end = date_create('11:00:00PM');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT30M');

while ($start <= $end) {
    echo $start->format('H:i:s');
    $start->add($interval);
}
```